# ROR: sending an object in response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 ruby on rails apps. With app A I post app B some data (in the form of a hash). I then want app B to send a hash on this data (with some modifications) back to app A in the response. 
I have tried the code below 
 App A

```
response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, params)
quotes.push(response.body)
```

and in App B

```
details = get_details //returns a hash
respond_with details
```

But its not working. Is what im doing even possible? Is there a way I can place this hash in my response?
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution #1

If you use `respond_with` you need also specify formats which your app should respond to. For this you should use [respond_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to) method.

Example:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json

    def index
        details = get_details
        respond_with(details)
    end
end
```

Also check [this good article](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2009/08/embracing-rest-with-mind-body-and-soul/) about `respond_to` method.

#### Solution #2

Just use `render json: {...}` in your controller action.

Example:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
     def index
        details = get_details
        render json: details
    end
end
```

---

In your app A `response.body` will contain a string with the data from your app B. So you need to parse that string.

In your app A:

```
require 'json' # this is unnecessary if app A is a Rails app

response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, params)
parsed_response = JSON.parse(response.body)
quotes.push(parsed_response)
```

Comment: how would the json object appear in the response? in the response.body or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. The response.body will contain the data. But you need to parse it. I've updated my answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

The rails way to do that is using JSON as an exchange format. have a look at the guides for how to use that: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-json

It is also possible to use [ActiveResource](http://railscasts.com/episodes/94-activeresource-basics) for such a communication. It allows direct access to your rails API.

Comment: It's not the "Rails" way to do it, it's bigger than that, it's the web-way now days. Frameworks and languages that support JSON do it for cross-language compatibility. Rails does it for that reason.

Comment: @theTinMan you could also use XML :)

Comment: Yes, but XML and/or using SOAP, is so 2000's. JSON is a lot more compact and immediately usable. We could use CSV too.